# Understanding null object vs 0 as number

Tags: javascript, object, null, numbers

I was on Codewars trying to complete some of the tasks and one question asked

Create a toDense() function that given a sparse array it returns the respective dense array. I used a test case as shown in the following:

```
var sparse = [undefined, 2, null, , , 0, 6, null];
Test.assertSimilar( toDense(sparse), [2, 0, 6]);
```

My solution to the code was:

```
function toDense(sparse){
  function isBoolean(value)
  { 

    if(value >= 0)
    {
      if(!(typeof(value) === 'object'))
        return value;
    }

  }
return sparse.filter(isBoolean);

}
```

But I could not get the array to be [2,0,6], the array i got back was [2,6].My question is if null is an object and 0 is a number why didnt my if condition for 0 return the value?

Comment: What does your dense array look like?

Comment: @DavidTansey sorry about that added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error occurs because you return 0 to the filter function which evaluates that as falsey.

```js
var arr = [0,1,2,3];

console.log(arr.filter(function(v) { return v; }));
```

Comment: You should show how to fix `isBoolean` to solve this.

Comment: And the solution could be as simple as `return typeof(value) === 'number';`

Comment: @DTing after seeing your example then going over MDN documentation for it... I finally understand thank you.

Comment: The way the question is posed is somewhat ambiguous in terms of what toDense() is supposed to return. Not sure if i want to touch on the specifics of the implementation. Just pointing out what is causing the "missing" value.

Answer (score 0):

Your evaluation is tripped up by falsey conversions.

Replace

```
if(value >= 0)
```

With

```
if(value > 0 || value === 0)
```

This solves your assertion.